# How to find which Visual Studio Dependency is using a particular DLL?

Tags: visual-studio, dependencies

I have a VS 2022 solution with approximately 100 projects in it.
One particular project references several other projects, and also pulls in a dozen nuget packages.

When I build that project, it includes Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll in the bin folder. My project doesn't use it.

Is there a fast way to find out which dependency is including it in the bin? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project doesn't use it directly, but maybe a NuGet package uses it. Maybe you can try the [NDepend Project Dependency Diagram](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/project-dependency-diagram) feature that also shows dependencies to the referenced assemblies. To do so:

- [Download NDepend trial full featured](https://www.ndepend.com/download)
- Unzip and start **VisualNDepend.exe**
- on the **Start Page** click **Analyze .NET assemblies in folder**
- point the dialog to the folder that contains all your assemblies
- eventually check **Recursive child folder**
- Start analyze
- Go to the NDepend Dependency Graph panel > Filers > uncheck **Exclude Third-Party**
- Use the **Search** graph feature and type **Microsoft.ApplicationInsights** to see who is using it
  [image: NDepend choose assemblies]
  [image: NDepend Dependency Graph]

You can also right click the assembly > Show on Dependency Grap to see direct callers

[image: Right-click shown on dependency graph]

[image: Usage of an assembly]

Comment: Thank you, this was perfect! I was able to generate a dependency graph that included ApplicationInsights and the project I cared about and saw how the invocation tree passed through some other projects. Perfect!